# Overriding masterpage <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8"/> tag

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

I have a master page with this tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8"/>` .  Problem is my screen within master page runs angularjs 1.4, and was developed for chrome.  Now I'm told IE must also work.  We run IE 11 but master page forces IE8 compatibility.  Is there any way to OVERRIDE this (temporarily preferably)? when my screen (via wicket) is loaded?

simply placing `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE11"/>` in my HTML has no effect, also tried a java filter applying this, but the master page seems to take precedent.

Any help desperately appreciated!

EDIT -

would this work in my master page:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=9, IE=10, IE=11" >`

?

Comment: The terms "master page" and "screen" do not have a canonical meaning in mainstream web development. I suppose they're an Angular thing or something. You'll probably get more relevant answers if you use tags to indicate the precise technology you are using.

Comment: Not sure of the terminology.  My application is hosted within another application, which forms the menu screen.  This screen i call the "master page".  It forces IE11 to operate in IE8 mode, and this applies to all wicket screens within the application.  This is about as much clarification as i can give.

Comment: I've search for [wicket](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wicket&t=ffsb&ia=about) and found: *Apache Wicket, commonly referred to as Wicket, is a lightweight component-based web application framework for the Java programming language*. Are you 100% sure that you are using good old vanilla JavaScript? When I build HTML and need a given `<meta>` tag I simply type in in my code. Seriously, I can't figure out what prevents you from doing it.

Comment: So I have my JS in my project in eclipse.  This project is hosted  within another project, called iGSR, which houses a menu system for all other packages hosted on my weblogic server.  What wicket does is creates a screen linked to the Java backend and allows my JS to be run within this screen.  the "iGSR" screen is the "main screen".  adding tags to my angular project makes no difference, since the tag is only read WITHIN my wicket screen.

Comment: I'm more lost than ever. But I have the impression that you are coding in Java, which is an entirely [different language](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml) than JavaScript (despite the similar names).

Comment: My application is JavaScript.  In my java i have a .java class representing my .HTML page, which in turn references my JS scripts.  This .java class allows access to the wicket screen within my browser, which has been set up elsewhere.  Because of this, my page ONLY EXISTS within my wicket screen (Which is hosted in my main applications screen).  The point of this is to allow navigation (by changing the content of the wicket screen) without reloading the page.

Comment: So find where the meta tag is being added and remove it.

Comment: if it was this simple i wouldnt be here. some applications need IE8 support, others (mine for example) dont.  In fact mine needs 10+